# Etale morphisms and unramified extensions of number felds

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-number-theory, etale-cohomology

I have statements like unramified extensions of number fields are examples of etale morphisms. How exactly do unramified extensions of number fields give rise to etale morphisms?

Comment: What definition of etale morphism do you know? When you know that etale means flat and unramified it should be easy.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Note that if $L/K$ is an extension of number fields and $\mathfrak{p}$ is a prime of $K$, then $\mathfrak{p}(\mathcal{O}_K)_\mathfrak{q}=\mathfrak{q}^{e(\mathfrak{q}\mid\mathfrak{p})}$ for every prime $\mathfrak{q}\mid\mathfrak{p}$. Recall then that what if means for a map $\text{Spec}(\mathcal{O}_L)\to\text{Spec}(\mathcal{O}_K)$ to be unramified at $\mathfrak{q}$ is that if $\mathfrak{p}$ is its image, then $\mathfrak{p}\mathcal{O}_{\text{Spec}(\mathcal{O}_L),\mathfrak{q}}$ is the maximal ideal of $\mathcal{O}_{\text{Spec}(\mathcal{O}_L),\mathfrak{q}}$. Compare that to my first sentence and see what you get.